# How to handle Variable Sized inputs at the end of CNN layers before sending to the Loss Function

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, cross-entropy

I am dealing with variable sized inputs to a CNN and **I wanted to know how to feed it to a last FC layer to satisfy the requirement for the CrossEntropy Loss function**. Even if taken care for one sample, the subsequent sample would have different dimensions and can't be used in backpropagation. So I wanted to know a way or different ways this can be handled.

(P.S : Cropping the input to make it fixed size is being currently used and the query is for improvising)

Comment: Check Adaptive pooling layers. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place `torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(S)` right between your Last conv layers and 1st Fully connected layer.

Note that your fully connected layer should take input dimension of `S x S x no. of channels in last conv layer`

Comment: Thank you very much for that, that seemed to work. However, I was further wondering how it modifies the data and plays an impact the model and the results. I understand it is task specific but as I fail to send batches of different length data to the model, I was wondering if there is a way to send batches of variable data too.